Decrement value in SQL but not negative with C#
I want to reduce the amount of my product in the database from the product reduction panel. But if the entered number is more than my product amount, that is, if the amount decreases and becomes negative, I want it to give an error. I could not find this decision mechanism and the necessary commands, can you help me?
I mean I want to decrement the number (which is amount of product), but I do not want the number (amount of product) to be allowed to go negative. When input is greater than amount, I want to give an error like "We do not have enough product!"
This is how I try it
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stok"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
SqlCommand cmda;
SqlCommand cmdb;
con.Open();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM urunler WHERE barkod = '" + barkod.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM urunler WHERE adet >= '0' AND barkod = '" + barkod.Text + "'", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataSet dl = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
db.Fill(dl);

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    cmda = new SqlCommand("UPDATE urunler SET cikarTarih='" + cikarTarih.Text + "'WHERE barkod='" + barkod.Text + "'", con);
    cmdb = new SqlCommand("UPDATE urunler SET adet=adet-1 WHERE barkod='" + barkod.Text + "'", con);

    for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(adet.Text); i > 0 ; i--)
    {
        cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (dl.Tables[0].Rows.Count < 0)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "K", "swal('Hata', 'Ürün adedi yeterli değil!', 'error')", true);
        }
    }
    cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "K", "swal('İşlem Tamamlandı', 'Ürün adedi başarıyla güncellendi!', 'success')", true);
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "K", "swal('Hata', 'Aradığınız ürün bulunamadı!', 'error')", true);
}

con.Close();

Here is my solution!
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stok"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
SqlCommand cmda;
SqlCommand cmdb;
con.Open();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM urunler WHERE barkod = '" + barkod.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM urunler WHERE adet >='" + Convert.ToInt32(adet.Text) + "'AND barkod = '" + barkod.Text + "'", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataSet dl = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
db.Fill(dl);

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    if (dl.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        cmda = new SqlCommand("UPDATE urunler SET cikarTarih='" + cikarTarih.Text + "'WHERE barkod='" + barkod.Text + "'", con);
        cmdb = new SqlCommand("UPDATE urunler SET adet=adet-1 WHERE barkod='" + barkod.Text + "'", con);

        for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(adet.Text); i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "K", "swal('İşlem Tamamlandı', 'Ürün adedi başarıyla güncellendi!', 'success')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "K", "swal('Hata', 'Yeterli ürün bulunamadı!', 'error')", true);
    } 
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "K", "swal('Hata', 'Aradığınız ürün bulunamadı!', 'error')", true);
}

con.Close();


This code has several critical bugs, including critical SQL injection bugs. For starters, all you really need is a single UPDATE urunler  SET cikarTarih=@text, adet=adet-1 WHERE barkod=@barcode called through a SqlCommand. As it is, someone could type '; DROP TABLE Users;-- in the text field and delete a table. The current code won't prevent negative values either, because there's a very long time between reading the count and storing the new value. Some other connection could easily decrement the value in the meantime.

As well as SQL-Injection this code is clearly mixing up UI, business logic and DB operations (well on its way to being a "big ball of mud". At the very least you need a transaction to avoid concurrent use of this code messing everything when the same product is effected (really, shouldn't have a "product quantity", instead use the journal pattern to track inventory changes – ie. to proper inventory accounting).

In addition to the other problems, at the point you return an error to the caller that there isn't enough product, you've already set the remaining product to zero.

All this code can be replaced with a single SqlCommand :
var sql=@"UPDATE urunler  
SET cikarTarih=@text, adet=adet-1 
WHERE barkod=@barcode AND adet>0";

using(var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
using (var cmd=new SqlCommand(con,sql))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@barcode",SqlDbType.NVarchar,20).Value=barkod.Text ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@text",SqlDbType.NVarchar,20).Value=cikarTarih.Text ;

    var modified=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(modified=0)
    {
        //Update failed, notify user.
    }
}

The condition WHERE barkod=@barcode AND adet>0 will decrement the value only if it's above 0. UPDATE is atomic, so there's no way to run two UPDATEs concurrently and get a negative
The question's code doesn't guarantee there won't be negative values, because some other connection could easily read the same initial value and decrement it. To prevent this, an explicit transaction would be needed. A single UPDATE though doesn't need an extra transaction.
ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of affected rows.
The question's code suffers from serious SQL injection problems too. Should someone enter '; DROP TABLE urunler ;-- in cikarTarih.Text, the table will be deleted. This is very easy to avoid by using parameterized queries with strongly-typed parameters.

This code can be simplified even further using libraries like Dapper, eliminating the need to specify parameters explicitly. It's also possible to return the old or new values using the OUTPUT clause. This is a nice alternative to checking the number of modified rows, which can be affected by settings like SET NOCOUNT ON or triggers.
record Entry(string barkod,int adet, int old_adet);

var sql=@"UPDATE urunler  
SET cikarTarih=@text, adet=adet-1 
OUTPUT inserted.barkod,inserted.adet,deleted.adet as old_adet
WHERE barkod=@barcode AND adet>0";

using(var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    var affected_entries=con.Query<Entry>(sql,
                 new { 
                         barkod=barkod.Text,
                         text=cikarTarih.Text
                 });
    ...
}

Dapper will generate command parameters based on the names and types of the argument properties and map the result to result objects.

I think he was looping the decreasing values for some reason, while this code just decrements by one.

Just to observe/add: the return value from ExecuteNonQuery can be adversely impacted by ambient connection state (things like SET NOCOUNT ON); if this impacts any specific scenario, explicit use of things like @@ROWCOUNT or the OUTPUT clause can be useful. But the code as shown may also be totally fine in many (most?) cases.

I'd use Dapper and OUTPUT personally but I wanted to show how to properly use ADO.NET first, and make them explain the actual requirements. I've seen such copy-pasta code too often lately. Which isn't surprising given how complicated the ADO.NET documentation is for a newcomer. It still targets the VB6 programmers transitioning to WinForms, with too much attention given to DataAdapters and Datasets
